# Java8: "Translate" old ForEach Method into Lambda/Stream

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8, java-stream

after hours of hopeless search, I decided to create a question. 
I really didn't find anything how I can transform this old fashioned way of coding to stream/lambda .

Maybe there is someone, who can explain it to me. Thanks.

```
public double getSum() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (Product product : productList) {
        sum += product.getPrice();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it's better not to use double for float to represent currency. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following:

```
double sum = productList.stream().mapToDouble(product -> product.getPrice()).sum();
```

Comment: Alternatively, use a method reference instead of a lambda expression:        mapToDouble(Product::getPrice)

Comment: Note that you may get slightly different result compared to OP code as stream version implements Kahan summation which is resistant against error accumulation.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: with `double`s, you can always get differences, even with the same code.